# I have more than one apache instance running. How can I kill a particular instance

Tags: python, apache

I have more than one apache instance running. How can I kill a particular instance and all of its children, from a terminal or preferably from a Python application.

Comment: which OS are you running?

Comment: Linux, but should also work on Windows

Comment: not sure about windows but below answer i posted works for linux .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on Linux.

For listing the process

```
ps aux

USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.2  24188  2120 ?        Ss   14:28   0:00 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:28   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:28   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:28   0:00 [migration/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:28   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   14:28   0:00 [cpuset]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   14:28   0:00 [khelper]
```

To get particular process use:

```
ps aux | grep "apache"


 USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         101  0.0  0.2  24188  2120 ?        Ss   14:28   0:00 /sbin/init
```

Then kill process with PID

```
  kill -9 101
```